# failing to retrieve multiple checked value from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to retrieve mulitple checked value, which are being showed in JSP dynamically, retrieved from inbox folder of the mail server, just like in yahoo, or gmail. But whenever I select multiple checkboxes(or either one), I'm not able to retrieve their values, like subject and username. What should I have to do in JSP to retrieve those values in another JSP dynamically?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Post some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each check-box in a form should have the same name but different value. e.g.

```
...
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="SELECT_CB_1"
        name="SELECT_CB"
        value="1"
      /> Checkbox 1
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="SELECT_CB_2"
        name="SELECT_CB"
        value="2"
      /> Checkbox 2
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="SELECT_CB_3"
        name="SELECT_CB"
        value="3"
      /> Checkbox 3
...
```

Then when your form gets posted, you can use `HttpServletRequest` to retrieve the values of all checked boxes with the name `SELECT_CB`.

```
String[] checked_values = request.getParameterValues( "SELECT_CB" );
```

You may need to check for `null` if no checkboxes are selected.

In the previous example, if you check `SELECT_CB_1` and `SELECT_CB_3` then `checked_values` will contain `[ "1", "3" ]`

You can use these values then to retrieve other pieces of your puzzle, like subject and username.